# How can I make use of the standard TV Out UI on iOS?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any supported way of displaying the standard "TV Connected" UI with MPMoviePlayerViewController when an external display is connected? I may be missing something obvious but there doesn't seem to be any documentation about it, and there's nothing in the API that points towards enabling this functionality.

Our app already supports TV Out using some (rather nasty) custom code, but this started acting strangely with the release of iOS 6. We patched the existing release and sent it out to testers, but one of them began complaining that the UI looked different, and to my surprise he sent screenshots of the old app on iOS 5 using the normal "TV Connected" UI, which (as far as I knew) wasn't available to third party developers.

I know there are examples of using a UIWebView to achieve this functionality, but that's not suitable for us because we need to respond to notifications from the movie player in order to report playback state & progress to our server software. The standard UI also handles certain situations (e.g. AirPlay mirroring, which we can't detect with public APIs) more elegantly than we've managed to achieve with our custom code.